# Vulnerable to future vulnerabilities in OpenSSL Library

Tags: react-native, security

Vulnerability:

The React-Native application does not use the Google Play Service Updated Security Provider which may leave it vulnerable to future vulnerabilities in OpenSSL Library.

Details:

Android relies on a security Provider to provide secure network communications. However, from time to time, vulnerabilities are found in the default security provider. To protect against these vulnerabilities, Google Play services provides a way to automatically update a device's security provider to protect against known exploits. By calling Google Play services methods, your app can ensure that it's running on a device that has the latest updates to protect against known exploits.

whats the recommendation to be followed for react-native app to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Is this about a server side application written in react?

Comment: no, React-Native APP, Below is recommendation for android APP -https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider. What would the recommendation or solution to handle this in react-Native APP(android)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so I'll leave a comment, not an answer. I believe that by using a react-native app the natural consequence is not using the Googles security provider. It's a fact. Can't fight this one. I believe the proper way to handle this issue is to make application updates when security issues are found. That's it. You build an app, you need to manage it in case security flaws are found in your code, or in the code of the libraries you depend on.